# Why task exception not rethrown on GC.Collect

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, task

My understanding is that when a Task throws an exception, it's get stored and re-thrown when either one of (Result, WaitAll) property of Tasks is observed or when GC happened. Given that, I run following code.

```
Task t = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
{                    
    throw new Exception("Hello World");
});

for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++)
{
    Console.WriteLine(i);
}    

 GC.Collect();

 for (int a = 20; a < 30; a++)
 {
      Console.WriteLine(a);
 }
```

But when I run the code above, I except an exception to be thrown at GC.Collect but it does not happen, rather it continues to print output from the second loop. Where is my understanding wrong here?

Comment: Do you get the exception when you check the completion status of task?

Comment: @jags: Yes, I get "One or more errors occurred." in the exception property.

Answer (score 5):

In your example code, the `Task` object `t` is still in scope, so is not eligible for collection when you call `GC.Collect()`.

Apart from that, the behaviour changed between .NET 4.0 and .NET 4.5:

In .NET 4.0, unobserved exceptions will throw an exception on the finalizer thread, causing the process to crash.

In .NET 4.5, this behaviour was changed so unobserved exceptions are ignored by default. There is a config switch you can set to turn the old, strict behaviour back on.

[.NET 4.0: Tasks and Unhandled Exceptions](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2009/05/31/9674669.aspx)

[.NET 4.5: Task Exception Handling in .NET 4.5](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2011/09/28/10217876.aspx)

Comment: +1 This only happens when running in Debug mode because in Release, t would have been eligible earlier.

Comment: I set t=null; before call to GC.Collect(). That didn't make any difference

Comment: Are you using .NET 4.0 or .NET 4.5? Also, can you observe the exception using the `TaskScheduler.UnobservedTaskException` event?

Comment: Also, remember that the exception will be raised on the finalizer thread, not the thread that calls `GC.Collect()`. What happens if you call `GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers()` just after `GC.Collect()`?

Comment: Nice point, It did not make any difference though. I added GC.Collect(); GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers(); and then another GC.Collect(); after WaitForPendingFinalizers.

Comment: I am using .NET 4.0. I am not observing TaskScheduler.UnobservedTaskException

Comment: For me it repros when I set t to null directly after assigning it. I also set an infinite loop. Nothing else is necessary.

Comment: @Usr: Not sure what you mean by "it repros". Does it mean you get an exception?

Comment: @imak yes I can reproduce the exception.

Comment: @usr Strange. I don't get this exception when I Start without debugging  (Ctrl + f5). However when I Start with debugging (F5), I do get this exception. I am not sure what difference does that make as I have no breakpoint set.

Answer (score 0):

Since using Task is like using Thread which is executed separately (besides with main thread). So this way you can get the *Loop* output along with *GC.Collect* executed until the line of exception is executed by the Task.